# Domain of dependence for wave equation on bounded domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Consider a wave equation, say in $1+1$ dimensions for $\phi(x,t)$, on a bounded domain, say $x \in (0,L)$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$, with initial values $\phi(x,0)=u(x)$ and $\partial_t \phi(x,0)=v(x)$ and some boundary conditions.

We know that the solution to the wave equation in the domain of dependence is solely determined by the initial values. Now, if the boundary is outside the domain of dependence the boundary conditions shouldn't affect the solution.
But, if we try to solve the wave the equation using the separation of variables (if possible) or using eigenfunctions of the Laplace operator, then the boundary conditions are important because different types of boundary conditions may lead to different eigenfunction, no matter whether the boundary will be inside of the domain of dependence or not.

So what is my confusion here?

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion is that you need first to extend your initial conditions on $(0,L)$ to the whole real line. The way how you extend these conditions depends crucially on the type of boundary conditions at $0$ and $L$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? I still don't understand. If the wave doesn't 'hit' the boundary then there is no difference between, say Dirichlet and periodic boundary conditions, right?

Comment: No, not completely so. If the characteristics from a particular point do not hit the boundary then there will be no influence of the boundaries at this point, so your solution will be the same for any type of boundary conditions.

Comment: But this is what I meant. Then the solution would be same for all points from which the characteristics do not hit the boundary. But how is this possible, since e.g. for periodic boundary condition one has all eigenfunctions {1, sin, cos} for the Laplace operator and for the other just one of these eigenfunction? I'm still puzzled.

Comment: If you apply the separation of variables you will get different formulas for different boundary conditions but all these formulas will agree at the points $(t,x)$ where the signal from the boundaries did not get to yet. Just take two problems, something like $u(x)=x(1-x)$, with $u(t,0)=u(t,1)=0$ and $u_x(t,0)=u_x(t,1)=0$, and compute corresponding solutions in the form of Fourier series. For the triangle $x<1-t,x>t$ you will get the same solutions at each point, but the series themselves will be different.

Comment: So my confusion was that I presumed that different eigenfunction would give different results for those points, right? But what about you answer, namely about the extension to the whole real line? What did you mean by that?

Comment: I meant that for the wave equation (and for wave equation only) we can reduce a problem on a finite interval to the problem on the whole real line and use d'Alembert's formula. It is not a very useful approach since the formulas become ugly very fast, but if you want your solution at one or two points only it can be done relatively easy.

Comment: OK, I see now what you mean. But it's still a bit unintuitive to me. This means that 'locally' the topology of the problem is not important, as long as the wave doesn't hit the boundary. I saw that some physicists do numerics and simulations and they put artificially boundary conditions, mostly periodic boundary conditions, far away from the tails of initial values, and say that they are solving the problem on the whole manifold, let say the real number. I thought topology has indeed effect on the behavior of the solution, no matter whether the wave hits the boundary or not.

Comment: I have also another comment. If the boundaries are outside of the domain of dependence then one can use d'Alembert's formula without any problem. So why solving a problem on different topology, say circle in this case or torus in 3 spatial dimensions, doesn't matter?